can't open modal through button in php
<?php
$result = mysqli_query($con, $sql);

while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) { 
    echo '<tr><td>';
    echo '<h5 style="margin-left:6px; color:black;">' . $row['id'] . '</h5>';
    echo '</td><td>';
    echo '<img src="'. $row['imagem']. '" alt>';
    echo '<a href="#" class="user-link">'. $row['nome'] . '</a>';
    echo '</td><td>';
    echo '<h5 style="margin-left:-180px; color:black;">'. $row['idaluno'] . '</h5></td>';
    echo '<td class="text-center">';
    echo '<h5 style="margin-left:6px; color:black; margin-left:-297px;">'. $row['situacao'] .'</h5>';
    echo '</td><td>';
    echo '<h5 style="margin-left:15px; color:black;">'. $row['faltas'] .'</h5>';
    echo '</td><td>';
    
   echo '<a href="editar.php?idaluno='. $row['id']  .'"><i style="margin-left:10px;" class="fa-solid fa-pencil"> </i></a>';
    
    
    echo '
    
    <button id="myBtn">
        <i style="margin-left:10px;" class="fa-solid fa-trash"></i>
    </button>';
   echo ' </td></tr>';

} 
?>

 <button id="myBtn">
        <i style="margin-left:10px;" class="fa-solid fa-trash"></i>
    </button>


<div id="myModal" class="modal">

  <!-- Modal content -->
  <div class="modal-content">
    <span class="close">&times;</span>
    <p>Some text in the Modal..</p>
  </div>

</div>
<script>

// Get the modal
var modal = document.getElementById("myModal");

// Get the button that opens the modal
var btn = document.getElementById("myBtn");

// Get the <span> element that closes the modal
var span = document.getElementsByClassName("close")[0];

// When the user clicks on the button, open the modal
btn.onclick = function() {
  modal.style.display = "block";
}

// When the user clicks on <span> (x), close the modal
span.onclick = function() {
  modal.style.display = "none";
}

// When the user clicks anywhere outside of the modal, close it
window.onclick = function(event) {
  if (event.target == modal) {
    modal.style.display = "none";
  }
}
</script>

im trying to make a confirmation modal for trying to delete a row in sql, i have php loop the button for each row, but the button doesnt work inside php, i have the button outside the php loop aswell and it works
im new to php and javascript, i think this could be resolved through ajax requests but im lost on that too. please help

you have many buttons with the same id, which is not allowed and is certainly going to cause issues when you try to access them with getElementById, as here.

The issue is that the JavaScript code is set up to target a single button and a single modal. When generating multiple buttons in a loop using PHP, each button needs to have its unique identifier to target and display the modal. By dynamically generating unique IDs for each button and modal within your PHP loop.
<?php
$result = mysqli_query($con, $sql);

while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) { 
    $id = $row['id']; // Unique identifier for each row/modal
    echo '<tr><td>';
    echo '<h5 style="margin-left:6px; color:black;">' . $row['id'] . '</h5>';
    echo '</td><td>';
    echo '<img src="'. $row['imagem']. '" alt>';
    echo '<a href="#" class="user-link">'. $row['nome'] . '</a>';
    echo '</td><td>';
    echo '<h5 style="margin-left:-180px; color:black;">'. $row['idaluno'] . '</h5></td>';
    echo '<td class="text-center">';
    echo '<h5 style="margin-left:6px; color:black; margin-left:-297px;">'. $row['situacao'] .'</h5>';
    echo '</td><td>';
    echo '<h5 style="margin-left:15px; color:black;">'. $row['faltas'] .'</h5>';
    echo '</td><td>';
    
    echo '<a href="editar.php?idaluno='. $row['id']  .'"><i style="margin-left:10px;" class="fa-solid fa-pencil"> </i></a>';
    
    echo '<button id="myBtn'.$id.'" class="deleteBtn" data-id="'.$id.'">
        <i style="margin-left:10px;" class="fa-solid fa-trash"></i>
    </button>';
    echo '</td></tr>';

    echo '<div id="myModal'.$id.'" class="modal">
        <div class="modal-content">
          <span class="close" data-id="'.$id.'">&times;</span>
          <p>Are you sure you want to delete this row?</p>
          <a href="delete.php?id='.$id.'" class="confirm-delete">Delete</a>
        </div>
      </div>';
}
?>

<script>
// Function to handle showing the modal
function showModal(modalId) {
    var modal = document.getElementById(modalId);
    modal.style.display = "block";
}

// Function to handle closing the modal
function closeModal(modalId) {
    var modal = document.getElementById(modalId);
    modal.style.display = "none";
}

// Event listener for the delete buttons
document.querySelectorAll('.deleteBtn').forEach(function(button) {
    button.onclick = function() {
        var id = this.getAttribute('data-id');
        showModal('myModal' + id);
    };
});

// Event listener for the close buttons
document.querySelectorAll('.modal .close').forEach(function(span) {
    span.onclick = function() {
        var id = this.getAttribute('data-id');
        closeModal('myModal' + id);
    };
});

// Event listener to close the modal when clicking outside of it
window.onclick = function(event) {
    if (event.target.classList.contains('modal')) {
        event.target.style.display = "none";
    }
}
</script>


Did you create this answer with ChatGPT?
